# Downloading telegram videos from a premium channel

Tags: download, telegram, subscription

I never have used Telegram before, I just downloaded both in my phone and in my pc the Telegram app in order to subscribe to a private channel where I paid a subscription. I think that the model has made unavailable the possibility to download her videos because of piracy or maybe I just don’t know how to download a video in telegram. 1. If this girl made unavailable the download of her videos, Does exist a method for a nontechsavvy like me to download the telegram content that I paid? 2. Telegram does not allow this and Im just ignorant? if that is the case what should I do in order to download her content ?